# Is there a way to break an Users Input with a key not allowed in the list?

Tags: python

I'm writing a program that asks users to choose from a list of numbers, and when they choose "0," it prints the count, average, minimum, and max of all previously entered values ( the last 0 should not be included in the calculation). And I can't seem to figure out the if break code.

```py
userList = input('Please enter a list of numbers by space. Put 0 to calculate the sum, average, minimum and maximum: ').split()

if len(userList) == 0:
    break 


for i in range (0, len(userList)):
     userList[i] = int(userList[i]) 


print (sum(userList))
print (max(userList))
print (min(userList))
```

Comment: Put `if userList[i] == "0": break` _inside_ the `for` loop.

Comment: Why a 0 in the input list?  Seems 0 would be used to signal user was done entering numbers when they were entering the numbers one at a time rather than a space-separated list.

Comment: The `.split()` method has already handled the splitting why did you still use `list()`? Because `.split()` method returns a `list`.

Comment: your code is not formatted correctly.

the if statement with the `break` is wrongly indented. It should have the same indentation level as the line above
Further: `break` will exit a loop, but the place where you have the `break` command is not in a loop.

If above code would be in a function, then you could use `return` instead of `break`.

However this doesn't seem to be the case.

If you don't want to put the code into a function you could replace `break` with `sys.exit()`  (if you add the line `import sys` at the beginning of your script

Comment: considering my previous comment. All this makes only sense if you want to do nothing / abort if the users enters nothing and in this case the condition should be:
`if len(userList) == 0:` (without the double quotes)

Or do you really want, that if a users enters

`1 2 3 0 4 5`
you get the `max`, `min`, `sum` of the numbers 1, 2 and 3 ?
In that case look at @Johnny Mopp's comment

Comment: You've already had a lot of suggestions here, but there's a problem in `if len(userList) == "0"`.  `len` returns an integer, not a string.  You would need `if len(userList) == 0`, but since an empty list is considered False, you could also say `if not userList:`.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you make use of the below code, It should definitely solve the problem.

The steps used are:

- Accepted a list of number separated by space from the user
- Make used of the `.split()` method to change the string accepted to `list`
- Check whether the user inputs a list of number by placing `userList` in the `if` statement. If the user did not input anything the value of the `userList = []` which will make the `if` statement evaluates to `False`.
- Convert all the value inputted to an integer but if an exception is raised, display "Only numbers are allowed!" and exit the program.
- Print all the calculation to the screen if the conversion from `string` to `int` runs successfully.

```py
import sys

userList = input('Please enter a list of numbers separated '
                'by space to calculate the sum, average, '
                'minimum and maximum\n').split()

if userList:
    try:
        userList = [int(num) for num in userList]
    except ValueError:
        print('Only numbers are allowed!')
        sys.exit()
    print('Sum:', (list_sum := sum(userList)))
    print('Average:', list_sum/len(userList))
    print('Minimum:', min(userList))
    print('Maximum:', max(userList))
```